# Removing haskamot when reprinting a sefer

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, rabbis, business, publications

I have heard that, recently, some publishers who reprint old sefarim remove some *haskamot* (approbations) from the book when they reprint it.

(Specifically, I heard that some Israeli *chareidi* publishers remove the *haskamot* of R' Kook and other Zionist rabbis whom they disagree with.)

- Is this true?
- If it is, are there any halachot regarding leaving in the original *haskamot* when one reprints a book?


  - Perhaps they are now misrepresenting the book, or showing disgrace to the works of rabbi, or similar?

Comment: 1) Yes 2) No 2a) Not really, nobody reads those things anyways

Comment: @Tatpurusha It may very well be that most people don't read the *content* of the haskamot, but very frequently they check *who* gave a haskama, and so I think there that removing one that previously appears because of a specific rabbi's political affiliation or opinion  are very reasonable grounds for being considered disgracing or slandering that rabbi.

Comment: See these links regarding [Toras Nazir of R. Hutner](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php?title=%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%A8) and [Pardes Yosef](http://seforim.blogspot.com/2011/11/censorship-of-rav-kook-and-other-hebrew.html), and while I have indications that this is true of other seforim (that I've seen are missing haskamos in new editions), I can't link to them, sorry

Comment: This has been documented by R Eitam Henkin Hyd in his [Studies in Halakhah and Rabbinic History](https://www.amazon.com/Studies-Halakhah-Rabbinic-History-Henkin/dp/159264581X) chapters 21-22

Answer (score 2):

When they reprinted "Toras HaNazir" by R' Yitzchak Hutner, they left out the Haskama of his teacher, R' Kook! ([See Chabapedia](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php?title=%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%97%D7%A7_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%A8))

R' Kook was of course, one of the greatest Rabbis of the time, and recognized as such by R' Hutner.

Why is this wrong? It is an obvious 'bizayon', disgrace to the Rav and lack of Derech Eretz. While not actual 'sheker', falsehood, it is purposely giving the wrong impression!

Comment: Thanks for [telling us](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTOaBUlGQ2mkuxMgLdjzRaAc-Pfa4xNcZUEy39bXsQzXp_yYWh) that it's wrong...

Comment: I don't doubt for a minute that this is true and premeditated, And I'm sure we can all guess why. But have you proven any of that in this answer?

Comment: This has been documented by R Eitam Henkin Hyd in his [Studies in Halakhah and Rabbinic History](https://www.amazon.com/Studies-Halakhah-Rabbinic-History-Henkin/dp/159264581X) chapters 21-22